# How do I re-apply a skill point?

Tags: borderlands

I applied one of the points I earned as I rank up on a skill I don't want. Is there any way to undo that and apply the point to a different skill?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; you have to purchase a skill reset from any New-U station; and reapply them all.

Comment: The skill reset is relatively cheap.